# Como faço pra criar um contador dentro de um FORELSE ou FOREACH no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, php-7, laravel-blade

Estou exibindo uma lista de membros do sistema. Mas gostaria de exibir apenas 10 membros utilizando a sintaxe  @forelse no Laravel.
Como faço para implementar um contador que exiba apenas os 10 primeiros registros na view Blade? Não encontrei nada na web me mostrando isso. Segue o código:

```
 @forelse ($members as $member)
        @if($member->private_profile == 0)
        <div class="flow-root mt-6">
          <ul class="-my-5">
            <li class="py-4 border border-b-0 border-r-0 border-l-0 border-gray-200">
              <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                  @if($member->url_avatar)
                  <img
                    class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                    title="{{$member->getUsername()}}"
                    src="{{$member->url_avatar}}"
                  />
                  @else
                  <img
                    class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                    title="{{$member->getUsername()}}"
                    src="/img/logo-avatar-user.png"
                  />
                  @endif
                </div>
                <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
                  <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 truncate">{{$member->name}}</p>
                  <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">{{$member->job}}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <a
                    {{-- onclick="window.location={{ $group->getUrl() . '/' . $group->name }}" --}}
                    href="/perfil/{{$member->id}}"
                    class="inline-flex items-center shadow-sm px-2.5 py-0.5 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-full text-gray-700 bg-white"
                  >
                    Ver perfil
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
        @empty
          <div class="-ml-2 text-sm text-gray-400">Esta Comunidade ainda não possui membros.</div>
        @endforelse
```

Comment: SeuModel::limit(10)->get()  ou então usaria a paginação do Laravel 
SeuModel::paginate(10) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results. Deve atender o que precisa

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@forelse($members->take(10) as $member)
resto do código..
```

Comment: Valeu meu amigo.. Funcionou... Abraços

Comment: @Iso0406 Isso resolve o problema em partes mas imagina a sobrecarga no banco se vc tiver 100k de registros no banco. Se for usar 10 registros não tem sentido carregar tudo, use no mínimo limit (sql) ao buscar os dados